# How to embed graphic into Android Video during recording

Tags: android, video

Is there an API call or library to embed graphic into Android video during recording.  I want to imprint a timestamp directly onto the video.  I have seen discussions of intercepting the bit stream but I am concerned about a home-grown solution like this having compatibility and performance issues.  Currently I add it in post-processing using ffmpeg which has issues with file timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

I have some ideas for you:

- Record using GLSurfaceView(check [Rotoscope](https://github.com/mobooya/Rotoscope) for example) or TextureView
- Use GLES20.glReadPixels() for GLSurfaceView or getBitmap() for TextureView to get bitmap data
- Create Canvas from bitmap then draw anything you want

Have fun!